Issue with Redis Cache TTL being set in milliseconds instead of seconds with NestJS
I'm encountering an issue where the TTL for our Redis cache is set in milliseconds instead of seconds. Our service uses NestJS, where we set the TTL to 1 hour (expecting it to be in milliseconds, as guided in the NestJS documentation). However, when setting this TTL in milliseconds, Redis doesn't convert it as expected, resulting in a much longer TTL (about 41 days).
According to NestJS documentation (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching)
cache-manager version 4 uses seconds for TTL (Time-To-Live). The current version of cache-manager (v5) has switched to using milliseconds instead. NestJS doesn't convert the value, and simply forwards the ttl you provide to the library. In other words:
If using cache-manager v4, provide ttl in seconds
If using cache-manager v5, provide ttl in milliseconds
Documentation is referring to seconds, since NestJS was released targeting version 4 of cache-manager.

We are currently using these versions:
"@nestjs/cache-manager": "^2.2.2",
"cache-manager": "^5.2.4",

This suggests that we should provide TTL in milliseconds, but this doesn’t appear to be working as expected. Instead of converting to the expected 1 hour, it’s stored as an excessive 41-day TTL in Redis.
Questions:

Is there a way to ensure the TTL is set correctly in Redis with milliseconds?
Is there a configuration setting or workaround we need to use in NestJS or cache-manager to handle this discrepancy?

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
